# No matching factory method found: factory method 'aspectOf() when deploy Spring application in Weblogic

Tags: spring, weblogic

Current application works fine in tc-server/Tomcat and Jboss, but when deployed in Websphere (12), I get

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'applicationAspect' defined in 
ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/spring/app-context.xml]: No matching factory method found: factory method 'aspectOf()'
```

and its merely a bean I defined in the context for the aspect

```
<bean id="applicationAspect" class="com.my.app.myaspects" factory-method="aspectOf" />
```

This is all happens when I import and deploy the war file in Weblogic Oracle Enterprise pack for Eclipse.

I didn't change class-loader. just add a class path in  in weblogic.xml for JPA purpose

Here I really want to understand why WebLogic behave so differently on Spring aspect, is it because I was deploying in a war file? I doubted.

Comment: Do you use compile or runtime weaving? Just keep track of your aspects, which should be also "patched" (see [this topic](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29012515/spring-factory-method-aspectof-is-not-working-when-we-deploy-the-application-f) and [that topic](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12144606/no-matching-factory-method-found-factory-method-aspectof)). If you use runtime weaving, make sure you have `<context:load-time-weaver />` in your context, put breakpoint on [`DefaultContextLoadTimeWeaver#createServerSpecificLoadTimeWeaver()`](http://bit.ly/18WBybj) and check what's going on.

Comment: @dma_k Thanks for the sugguestion. We are on compile weaving. I eventually sort it out, some how maven didn't include the aop.xml into the generated war, that xml file defined the mapping to the aspect.